# Oh-My-Zsh overriding my function?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use ZSH with Oh My Zsh and I am trying to define a function called `git`, as such:

```
function git() { echo "I'm happy because I am executed!" }
```

I have placed the function definition in `$ZSH/custom/general.zsh`.

Everything else in this file works (I have a bunch of aliases there) except this function.

Running `which git` outputs:

```
git () {
    case $1 in
        (commit|blame|add|log|rebase|merge) exec_scmb_expand_args "$_git_cmd" "$@" ;;
        (checkout|diff|rm|reset) exec_scmb_expand_args --relative "$_git_cmd" "$@" ;;
        (branch) _scmb_git_branch_shortcuts "${@:2}" ;;
        (*) "$_git_cmd" "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

Removing `git` from `plugins=( ... )` didn't work. Trying to find this function in Oh My Zsh yielded no results.

I read the source code of `oh-my-zsh.sh`, and it seems the `custom` directory is loaded after all of OMZ's files, so it didn't make any sense to me, that when I placed my function **at the bottom of** `.zshrc` it worked.

Any Ideas on how to keep the function in the `custom` folder? I would like to keep things organized.

Comment: Have you started a new login shell after you update the code?

Comment: Of course, I run `~ $ source .zshrc && git` after each change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably installed `scm_breeze`, and my theory is that in your `.zshrc` the sourcing of `scm_breeze.sh` is preceeded by `oh-my-zsh.sh`. And if you put your git function definition at the very end of `.zshrc`, then you probably exceed the `scm_breeze.sh`, so that's the reason why it works.

1. Try to move the line that sources `oh-my-zsh.sh` to the very end of your `.zshrc` or at least in a position where it exceeds the sourcing of `scm_breeze.sh`. Restart zsh and see if it works.
   (alternatively you can remove `scm_breeze.sh` completely)
2. If it still doesn't work, then back up your `.zshrc` and all your `oh-my-zsh` stuffs, then create an empty `.zshrc`, delete and reinstall `oh-my-zsh` with  `curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh` and then put `function git() { echo "I'm happy because I am executed!" }` in `$ZSH/custom/general.zs`, **I have tested this, it worked for me**. After that you can gradually reapply your former settings, step-by-step checking what exactly breaks your configuration.